# how to create following red mark box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a modal popup in my webpage, but I don't know enough about them to make one on my own. Can you help me with any links to tutorials, code, etc.?

This is what I want my modal to look like:

[image]

Comment: can you give me any example link

Comment: SO isn't to get free code. Show us what you've tried and what hasn't worked, then people can work off of that.

Comment: @user1493448 check my answer for the one exactly you are looking for.

Comment: this pop up box looking difference than normal pop up box. I know how to create normal pop up box. But it's totally different than normal pop up box. do you have any link

Comment: @user1493448 Check the link below the comment, in the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into jQuery UI Dialogue http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Names for that are: pop up, modal box, and dialogue box, though I'm sure there are plenty of others.

Comment: thank you so much imkingdavid for solving my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to mark this answer as accepted if it is the one you're going with.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a pop up window with HTML](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_popup_window_code.cfm)

Probably not the best place to point. But it will show/give you the code to create a popup window.

Customization of that is up to you.

Future Refernce: **Do Your Research First**

Comment: That is a separate window; the example he gave was a modal div in the page.

Comment: this pop up box looking different from your link pop up box and  know this. do you have any link creating my red mark pop up box

Answer (score 0):

Check Twitter Bootstrap's Modals; they look something like that:

[Twitter Bootstrap | GitHub](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

Stack overflow is not a place for you to get code. It is a place to post what you have already done and ask for help with revisions.

Comment: Thanks david, your link also help me for solving my problem.